# How to use a 'Hibernate Types' library type in a single native query that selects Postgres arrays?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-types

I have a query that returns a Postgres array of UUIDs:

```
SELECT e.id, e.date,
ARRAY
(
 SELECT cs.api_id FROM event_condition_set ecs
 JOIN condition_set cs on cs.id = ecs.condition_set_id
 WHERE ecs.event_id = e.id
) AS condition_set_ids,
...
```

And then create and run this query as a native query: `Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryString);`

Since Hibernate can normally not deal with these Postgres arrays, I use Vlad's Hibernate Types library.

However, currently I need to register this UUIDArrayType globally in my application:

```
public class PostgreSQL95CustomDialect extends PostgreSQL95Dialect {

    public PostgreSQL95CustomDialect() {
        super();
        this.registerHibernateType(Types.ARRAY, UUIDArrayType.class.getName());
    }

}
```

Aside from the fact this is a bit ugly, it also leaves no room for other types of arrays.

(Note I also tried registering a generic `ListArrayType` but this throws a NullPointerException during execution of the query.)

I have also tried registering it as a scalar type:

```
query.unwrap(org.hibernate.query.NativeQuery.class)
            .addScalar("condition_set_ids", UUIDArrayType.INSTANCE);
```

But this makes the entire query only return a single UUID, which is very strange and seems bugged.

Is there a way to ONLY use this `UUIDArrayType` specifically in this query?

(Please don't suggest using `array_agg` because the performance is terrible for this case)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here. After waiting for a while and updating to the most recent library version (I'm on `2.19.2` right now) I don't have any issues anymore with the scalar types registration as I mentioned in my question, i.e.:

```
query.unwrap(org.hibernate.query.NativeQuery.class)
            .addScalar("condition_set_ids", UUIDArrayType.INSTANCE);
```

So it appears to just have been a bug and I can now avoid the global registration in favor of using scalars.

Additional information: after migrating to Spring Boot 3 with Hibernate 6, we don't need this library at all anymore.

Answer (score 0):

you can call native queries using custom Hibernate types as follows:

```
String myJsonbData = ...;
String[] myStringArr = ...;
final String queryStr = "select your_function(?, ?, ...)"; // ? for each param
entityManager
    .createNativeQuery(queryStr)
    .setParameter(1, new TypedParameterValue(JsonBinaryType.INSTANCE, myJsonbData))
    .setParameter(2, new TypedParameterValue(StringArrayType.INSTANCE, myStringArr));
```

This is just an example, but as a rule of thumb, you need to instantiate a `new TypedParameterValue`.

Comment: I need it to return the uuid array correctly though, I don’t have a problem with the params I have to pass